# UIGestureRecognizer on UILabel inside UIView inside UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I have a programatically created UILabel that uses autolayout inside a UIView, inside a UIScrollView. Initially it is off-screen and then slides onto screen (by animating the change of the autolayout constraint constants). I am trying to add a gesture recognizer (single tap) to the UILabel but the gesture never gets recognized. If I add one to the UIView, the gesture recognizer works. Does anyone know what the solution to this would be? Is this a problem caused by autolayout?
Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is definitely to do with the scrollview swallowing touches. I've just created the same label outside of the scrollview and the gesture recogniser works fine!

**EDIT 2**
I can create the label within the scroll view using Interface Builder, but programmatically it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the label was embedded within 2 views, within the view in the scrollview. Taking it out of this seemed to solve them problem...

Answer (score 1):

You have to check `User Interaction Enabled` in the UILabel

If you are adding a UITapGestureRecognizer programmatically:

In `viewDidLoad` i added the following code:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("myaction"))
self.label.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

with the selector:

```
func myaction() {
    println("Label tapped")
}
```

where `self.label` is the reference outlet of the label being tapped.

Comment: 1. have you created an IBAction from the tap gesture recognizer to the viewController to check if its working?

2. have you connected the label and the gesture recognizer (i.e. does right clicking  gestureRecognizer show a 
referencing outlet)?

3. your view hierarchy is UIViewController > UIView > UIScrollView > UIView > UILabel?

Comment: 1. No I haven't because it's all programmatically created. But I know the code works because I can use it else where and it works fine. 2. I know I have added the gesture recognizer to the label correctly. 3. my view hierarchy is UIViewController->View->View->ScrollView->View and then add the UILabel to that view. (it it a little complicated since I have other stuff going on)

Comment: @Tometoyou please check the updated Code
and also update your question with your code snippet if it still does not work